# How to get rid if of unneeded string before # ? (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Whenever I access the url angular app remains polluted with hashtag. Is there a way to get rid of **someRandomString** from url after the angular has initialised.

Enter url in browser: `url.dev/someRandomString`

After that angular will redirect(without reloadding page) me to: `url.dev/someRandomString#/` idealy it should be `url.dev/#/`

I am using ui-router and angular. The html5 mode is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can.**

Just set `/` as argument for `otherwise()` method of `$urlRouterProvider` provider of `uiRouter` module (which you already use) :

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // Your custom routes
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    });

    // Redirect to 'url.dev/#/' if no route matched
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  }
]);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Redirects to `url.dev/someRandomString#/` because #/ is the root. Basically it is the same configuration I have now.